# jQuery scroll() in Safari on Mac issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I'm having an issue on a website I'm building where I'm applying certain CSS styles on scroll events. Here is a small example of what I have:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {

            $('nav.navbar .navbar-brand img').css({'height' : '32', 'width' : '142', 'margin-top' : '0px'});

        } else {

            $('nav.navbar .navbar-brand img').css({'height' : '43', 'width' : '187', 'margin-top' : '-5px'});

        }   
    });
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, but Safari is causing some issues. It seems that whenever I scroll, the Javascript briefly starts to change the CSS but pauses until the scroll stops, and then finishes the transition to the new style.